# How can I tell which reason code an exception has thrown in JavaCard?

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, smartcard, javacard

I'm trying to find out why a `CryptoException` has been thrown in my applet but I'm struggling.

I've tried this:

```
catch (CryptoException e) {
    if (e instanceof CryptoException.ILLEGAL_USE) {
        //send certain apdu
    }
}
```

And this:

```
catch (CryptoException e) {
    if (e == (short)5) {
    //send certain apdu
    }
}
```

And also this:

```
catch (CryptoException e) {
    if (e == CryptoException.ILLEGAL_USE) {
    //SEND CERTAIN APDU
    }
}
```

But none of them seem to work and I can't find the right way to use the reason code to send a specific apdu. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does `CryptoException` have methods that allow you to retrieve the reason? Comparing the exception instance itself with any codes or enum constants obviously won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`getReason()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/CardRuntimeException.html#getReason()) on the [`CryptoException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/CryptoException.html):

```
try {
    // . . .
} catch (CryptoException e) {
    if (e.getReason() == CryptoException.ILLEGAL_USE) {
        // SEND CERTAIN APDU
    }
}
```